# Need to know when the power button is clicked in android

Tags: android

I am working on understanding the key events in android. I got all the key events except the power button. I have googled it but I didn't find the better solution.

Few say that we can't access the power button in android. But my question is, how does the SOS feature of few devices work on power button click?

We can't assume that power button clicked on ON_SCREEN_OFF and ON_SCREEN_ON.

Please let me know is there a way to detect power button in android.

Comment: power button is not a regular key. It does not have key event. `the SOS feature of few devices work` because it is a system app, and it can access that events

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko Few SOS apps also work based on the power button click.

Comment: they likely detect screen on and off frequently from pressing power button

Comment: SCREEN_ON and SCREEN_OFF will not work properly since screen might get turn on and off, even you get some notifications, and if you get a call etc.

Comment: there is no other way, as I said. To improve accuracy - use many simultanuous on and off to detect, and filter them by time interval, like *need to press power button 10 times during 5 seconds. The screen for sure can't turn on and off due to anything except pressing power for 10 times during 5 seconds